# Combine a character value under one statement in R

Tags: r, regex, string, extract

I will need to combine an object under one umbrella.

Here is a sample object.

```
object <- c("Equal = (G1, 20, Slope[0]); Equal = (G1, 20, Slope[1]);", 
            "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[0]); Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[1]);",
            "Equal = (G1, 22, Slope[0]); Equal = (G1, 22, Slope[1]);")

> object
[1] "Equal = (G1, 20, Slope[0]); Equal = (G1, 20, Slope[1]);" 
    "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[0]); Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[1]);"
    "Equal = (G1, 22, Slope[0]); Equal = (G1, 22, Slope[1]);"
```

what I would like to do is as below:

```
"Equal = (G1, 20, Slope[0]), (G1, 20, Slope[1]),
(G1, 21, Slope[0]), (G1, 21, Slope[1]),
(G1, 22, Slope[0]), (G1, 22, Slope[1]);"
```

Basically, I need to

```
(1) combine all under one "Equal" statement.
(2) replace`;` with `,` between statements,
(3) keep one `;` at the end of the object.
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a little regex to do so.

```
gsub("(?!^);\\s{0,1}Equal =", ",", paste(object, collapse = ""), perl = T)

[1] "Equal = (G1, 20, Slope[0]), (G1, 20, Slope[1]), (G1, 21, Slope[0]), (G1, 21, Slope[1]), (G1, 22, Slope[0]), (G1, 22, Slope[1]);"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
gsub("[; ]+Equal =",',',paste(object, collapse = ''))

[1] "Equal = (G1, 20, Slope[0]), (G1, 20, Slope[1]), (G1, 21, Slope[0]), (G1, 21, Slope[1]), (G1, 22, Slope[0]), (G1, 22, Slope[1]);"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_extract_all()` from `stringr` to extract all texts surrounded by parentheses.

```r
library(stringr)

str_c("Equal = ", toString(unlist(str_extract_all(object, "\\(.+?\\)"))), ";")

# [1] "Equal = (G1, 20, Slope[0]), (G1, 20, Slope[1]), (G1, 21, Slope[0]), (G1, 21, Slope[1]), (G1, 22, Slope[0]), (G1, 22, Slope[1]);"
```